# SQL updates in PHP

Tags: c#, php, mysql, sql, unity-game-engine

I'm really new into PHP and SQL and I'm trying to learn how to use them with Unity.

First I created a new table in my database with Unity which worked OK. Now I want to update this table with some info, this info should come from Unity.
But it's not working; I'm not sure if it's my C# script or my PHP script. 
First, here's a snippet from my C# script:

```
IEnumerator InsertMemberData(string username,string day,int sale)
{
    //insert data to table
    WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
    form.AddField("usernamePost", username);
    form.AddField("currentDayPost", day);
    form.AddField("daySalePost", sale);

   UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post(updateDataTable, form);

    yield return www.Send();

    if (www.isError)
    {
        Debug.Log(www.error);
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("Form upload complete!");
    }
}
```

and now my PHP script

```
<?php

$servername = **********
$server_username = ***************
$server_password = ****************
$dbName = *****************

$username = $_POST["usernamePost"];
$currentDay = $_POST["currentDayPost"];
$daySale = $_Post["daySalePost"];

//Make Connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $server_username, $server_password, $dbName);
//Check Connection
if(!$conn)
{
    die("Connection Failed". mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "Update tbl_{$username} SET ".$currentDay." = ".$daySale." WHERE id=1";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if(!$result){
mysqli_error($conn);
echo "there was an Error!";
}
else echo "Evereything ok.";
?>
```

I just want to send in a specific table at a specific day a number.

Comment: `Update tbl_{$username}` do you really have a table for every user?

Comment: mh good question, i have to think about it.but for now yes, im just learning and testing

Comment: yes you should (re) think (about it) since and if you plan on going live with this, you will have one humongous database. Plus, I didn't see you actually executing that query, if that's your full code that is.

Comment: u mean like`$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
 
 if(!$result)echo "there was an Error!";
 else echo "Evereything ok.";`

Comment: pretty much, yes.

Comment: and adding `mysqli_error($conn)` in case there are errors, in the `if(!$result)` part.

Comment: ok i added this, didnt worked, except when i change my variables to `$username = "Oliver";
$currentDay = "eins";
$daySale = "2837";` But i wont to send the Info from Unity, so somthing is wrong i my c# script ?

Comment: if this is C# related, I can't help you with that.

Comment: maybe i shoul use GET instead of POST ?

Comment: Ok i  re think all a bit and now it work. But i got another question:   $sql = "UPDATE userinfo SET {$day} = '{$value}'**WHERE id='{$idNumber}'** ";        i can POST day value with no problems but with the id it dont work. Did i miss somthing?

Comment: Fixed it,thanks to me.

Comment: great, you know that Stack lets you post your own answer. I'd be glad to upvote it if you provide a clear and detailed answer as to how you fixed it. This will also help future visitors to the question to also understand, and if they also had the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I re-thought my work. So no table for every user, only on Table with all user/userinfos  and thinks a want to save/load.

C# script is more or less the same:

```
IEnumerator InsertMemberData(string username,string day,int sale)
```

to

```
IEnumerator InsertMemberData(string username,string day,**string** sale)
```

and my PHP script :

```
    if($conn)
{
    $sqlCheck = "SELECT ID FROM userinfo WHERE username = '".$username."' ";
    $resultCheck = mysqli_query($conn,$sqlCheck);


    if($resultCheck){
        if(mysqli_num_rows($resultCheck)>0)
        {
            $sqlUpdate = "UPDATE userinfo SET {$day} = '".$value."' WHERE username = '".$username."' ";

            $resultUpdate = mysqli_query($conn,$sqlUpdate);

            if($resultUpdate)
            {
                echo("Update success");
            }else
            {
                echo("Update Failed");
            }
        }
    }else{
        echo("There was an Error.");
    }   
}
```

I'm not really sure why, but this worked perfect for me.

Comment: Depending on how you supply data to this code, you may have a SQL injection vulnerability here. Be careful about concatenating user-supplied data into SQL queries.

Comment: Over the Time i changed a lot of this Code to more complexity.. i also think about to switch to a Rest Api. Thanks

Comment: Are you using bound parameters in the new solution? Thankfully your database connector (MySQLi) does support them.

Comment: Not at the moment.Thx for the advive.